# Questionable SQL practice - Order By id rather than creation time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

So I have an interesting question that I am not sure is considered a 'hack' or not. I looked through some questions but did not find a duplicate so here it is. Basically, I need to know if this is unreliable or considered bad practice.

I have a very simple table with a unique auto incrementing id and a created_at timestamp.
 (simplified version of my problem to clarify the concept in question)

```
+-----------+--------------------+
| id        |created_at          |
+-----------+--------------------+
| 1         |2012-12-11 20:35:19 |
| 2         |2012-12-12 20:35:19 |
| 3         |2012-12-13 20:35:19 |
| 4         |2012-12-14 20:35:19 |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

Both of these columns are added dynamically so it can be said that a new 'insert' will **ALWAYS** have a greater id and **ALWAYS** have a greater date.

**OBJECTIVE** -
very simply grab the results ordered by created_at in descending order

**SOLUTION ONE** - A query that orders by date in descending order

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

**SOLUTION TWO** - A query that orders by ID in descending order

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Is solution two considered bad practice? Or is solution two the proper way of doing things. Any explanation of your reasonings would be very helpful as I am trying to understand the concept, not just simply get an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, sorting by id can and will take advantage of indexing. You should include relevant portions of your schema to the question.

Comment: While I don't know if there's an 'official way' to go about this, the 'order by' query exists to do just that. To order by a column. The only drawback I see is, that the timestamp may have duplicates (two inserts in the same second) AND that the query may be slower, due to a missing index.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In typical practice you can almost always assume that an autoincrement id can be sorted to give you the records in creation order (either direction). However, you should note that this is not considered portable in terms of your data. You might move your data to another system where the keys are recreated, but the created_at data is the same.

There is actually a pretty good [StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730762/sql-best-practices-ok-to-rely-on-auto-increment-field-to-sort-rows-chronologic) of this issue.

The basic summary is the first solution, ordering by created_at, is considered best practice. Be sure, however, to properly index the created_at field to give the best performance.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the discussion, must have missed it in my research

Comment: Why the downvote? I like to at least see an explanation for future reference.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't rely on ID for anything other than that it uniquely identifies a row.  It's an arbitrary number that only happens to correspond to the order in which the records were created.

Say you have this table

```
ID  creation_date
1   2010-10-25
2   2010-10-26
3   2012-03-05
```

In this case, sorting on ID instead of creation_date works.

Now in the future you realize, oh, whoops, you have to change the creation date of of record ID #2 to 2010-09-17.  Your sorts using ID now report the records in the same order:

```
1   2010-10-25
2   2010-09-17
3   2012-03-05
```

even though with the new date they should be:

```
2   2010-09-17
1   2010-10-25
3   2012-03-05
```

Short version: **Use data columns for the purpose that they were created.** Don't rely on side effects of the data.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of differences between the two options.

---

The first is that they can give different results.

The value of `created_at` might be affected by the time being adjusted on the server but the `id` column will be unaffected. If the time is adjusted backwards (either manually or automatically by time synchronization software) you could get records that were inserted later but with timestamps that are before records that were inserted earlier. In this case you will get a different order depending on which column you order by. Which order you consider to be "correct" is up to you.

---

The second is performance. It is likely to be faster to `ORDER BY` your [clustered index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html).

> **How the Clustered Index Speeds Up Queries**
>
> Accessing a row through the clustered index is fast because the row data is on the same page where the index search leads.

By default the clustered key is the primary key, which in your case is presumably the `id` column. You will probably find that `ORDER BY id` is slightly faster than `ORDER BY created_at`.

Comment: MySQL doesn't care about clustered indexes.  InnoDB tables aren't likely to store records in creation order.

Comment: @Javier: Thanks for your comment. I have added a link to the documentation about clustered indexes, and quoted from the documentation.

Comment: hum... i stand corrected.  they must have creeped into the InnoDB implementation while i wasn't looking.

Answer (score 4):

Primary keys, especially of surrogate type, do not usually represent any kind of meaningful data aside from the fact that their mere function is to allow for uniquely identifiable records. Since dates in this case do represent meaningful data that has meaning outside of its primary function I'd say sorting according to dates is a more logical approach here.

Answer (score 4):

Ordering by id orders by *insertion* order.

If you have use cases where insertion can be delayed, for example a batch process, then you must order by created_at to order by time.

Both are acceptable if they meet you needs.