# mysql query row order by inserted sequence

Tags: mysql

Accounting schema design using MYSQL

I excluded datetime and timestamp solution. As two record may be inserted in a millisecond but yet in order.

auto-increment is not good practice as Schema design change in future will break the increment according to
[SQL Best Practices - Ok to rely on auto increment field to sort rows chronologically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730762/sql-best-practices-ok-to-rely-on-auto-increment-field-to-sort-rows-chronologic)

what I can think of now is

```
ORDER BY datetime desc, id desc
```

any suggestion?

Comment: `datetime DESC, id DESC` is exactly how to do it. The time is most important, and sub-order on an auto-increment value if it is present now. If you change your schema later and lose it, then you would not be able to sort these, but there really isn't a better way unless you build significantly more logic to increment another column when a timestamp already exists.

Answer (score 0):

referring to this post answer:
[Why doesn't MySQL support millisecond / microsecond precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572209/why-doesnt-mysql-support-millisecond-microsecond-precision)

MySQL version 5.6.4:

"MySQL now supports fractional seconds for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microsecond precision."

is microsecond good enough for you? That's 1M rows per sec!